# How would I make this Python program with lists/arrays Instead of multiple variables?

Tags: python, list, dice

I got this to work but am terrible at making lists/calling them.  Would anyone be able to compact this into list form? (Not for homework, finished already, just for learning opportunity/practice, so no hurry.)  I assume my count variable can be made into a list and called in the for loop and during the final prints.

This was for a dice game that tracked how many times a number came up after 2 dice were thrown and added together.  Pretty easy, I just suck at understanding lists, so explanations with code would be GREATLY apricated, my textbook does not expound on this topic enough.  First post on stack, excuse any messed up jargon or rules.  Thanks!

```
import random

count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
count5 = 0
count6 = 0
count7 = 0
count8 = 0
count9 = 0
count10 = 0
count11 = 0
count12 = 0

rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll? "))



for i in range(rolls):

    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Roll number 1 = " + str(die1))
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Roll number 2 = " + str(die2))
    total = die1 + die2
    print(total)


    if total == 2:
        count2 += 1
    elif total == 3:
        count3 += 1
    elif total == 4:
        count4 += 1
    elif total == 5:
        count5 += 1
    elif total == 6:
        count6 += 1
    elif total == 7:
        count7 += 1
    elif total == 8:
        count8 += 1
    elif total == 9:
        count9 += 1
    elif total == 10:
        count10 += 1
    elif total == 11:
        count11 += 1
    elif total == 12:
        count12 += 1


print("You rolled " + str(count2) + " 2's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count3) + " 3's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count4) + " 4's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count5) + " 5's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count6) + " 6's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count7) + " 7's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count8) + " 8's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count9) + " 9's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count10) + " 10's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count11) + " 11's")
print("You Rolled " + str(count12) + " 12's")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code little bit and I think if you use dictionary than it will be easy to use and understand.

```
import random

# count2 = 0
# count3 = 0
# count4 = 0
# count5 = 0
# count6 = 0
# count7 = 0
# count8 = 0
# count9 = 0
# count10 = 0
# count11 = 0
# count12 = 0

count = {i: 0 for i in range(2,13)}

rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll? "))



for i in range(rolls):

    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Roll number 1 = " + str(die1))
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Roll number 2 = " + str(die2))
    total = die1 + die2
    print(total)



    # if total == 2:
    #     count2 += 1
    # elif total == 3:
    #     count3 += 1
    # elif total == 4:
    #     count4 += 1
    # elif total == 5:
    #     count5 += 1
    # elif total == 6:
    #     count6 += 1
    # elif total == 7:
    #     count7 += 1
    # elif total == 8:
    #     count8 += 1
    # elif total == 9:
    #     count9 += 1
    # elif total == 10:
    #     count10 += 1
    # elif total == 11:
    #     count11 += 1
    # elif total == 12:
    #     count12 += 1

    count[total] += 1
# print("You rolled " + str(count2) + " 2's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count3) + " 3's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count4) + " 4's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count5) + " 5's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count6) + " 6's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count7) + " 7's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count8) + " 8's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count9) + " 9's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count10) + " 10's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count11) + " 11's")
# print("You Rolled " + str(count12) + " 12's")

for i in range(2,13):    
    print("You rolled " + str(count[i]) + " "+i+"'s")
```

Comment: Thank you for the before and after, I'm not at dictionaries yet but this makes sense.  Can you explain a bit how how the count[total] works and the count[i]?

Comment: Sure dictionary has keys and value ... in count dictionary, there are keys from 2 to 12 only .. and sum of the two dice is always between 2 and 12 .   Same thing is happening in count[i] part iam just looping from 2 to 12 and displaying the output .

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and lastly (I think) how does the count[I] know how many times the a total has been rolled?

Comment: @JonMH due to this line `count[total] += 1` every time a total is generated by the two dice `count` dictionary keep the value for that particular total ... And when iam trying to get the value through `count[i]` i am getting the value for example `i=2`  . count[2] will return value for the key 2

Comment: So I is for the entire list, got it.  Thank you very much for the help that's just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either a list or a dictionary here. I would tend toward a dictionary, which I think best represents the sort of sparse data structure you're going for here (what's the first element of your `count` list? It'll always be zero, but shouldn't it really be *nothing*? Does it make more sense that a zero has been rolled no times, or that it can't be rolled at all?)

That dictionary would be best defined simply as:

```
counts = {}

# You can also generalize your rolling 2d6!
def roll_dice(num_dice, sides):
    total = 0
    for _ range(num_dice):
        dieroll = random.randint(1, sides)
        total += dieroll
    return total

for _ in range(rolls):
    roll = roll_dice(2, 6)
    counts.setdefault(roll, 0) += 1  # this is using dict.setdefault

for roll, count in sorted(counts.items()):
    print("You rolled {} {}s".format(count, roll))
```

You could also use a `collections.Counter` to do this.

```
rolls = [roll_dice(2, 6) for _ in num_rolls]
# this will generate a list like [3, 12, 6, 5, 9, 9, 7, ...],
# just a flat list of rolls.

result = collections.Counter(rolls)
```

Comment: On the other hand, the underlying domain is sequential `(2..12)`, so lists are certainly fine to use here. You can iterate over the list in order. For a dictionary, you have to sort it first to ensure proper order (ugh!). They're also better in performance.

Comment: `plus1` for the `collections.Counter` though; it's the preferred solution to the problem.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq agreed -- it's a bit of a mixed bag. I prefer dictionaries for sparse data like this, but YMMV :)

Comment: Interesting, my book hasn't gotten to the def functions but I've tried them and will play with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of 11 zeroes:

```
counts = [0] * (12 - 2 + 1)
```

To increment a count:

```
counts[total - 2] += 1
```

All together now:

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    total = die1 + die2

    print(f"Roll number 1 = {die1}")
    print(f"Roll number 2 = {die2}")
    print(total)

    return total

min_count = 2
counts = [0] * (12 - min_count + 1)
rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll? "))

for i in range(rolls):
    total = roll_dice()
    counts[total - min_count] += 1

print('\n'.join(f"You rolled {x} {i + min_count}'s"
    for i, x in enumerate(counts)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your code a little:

```
from random import randint
rolls = int(input("How many times would you like to roll? "))
count = [0 for x in range(11)] #since 2 to 12 is 11 items
for i in range(rolls):
    die1 = randint(1, 6)
    print("Roll number 1 = " + str(die1))
    die2 = randint(1, 6)
    print("Roll number 2 = " + str(die2))
    total = die1 + die2
    print(total)
    #total will start with 2, while count index with 0, so
    #minus 2 to make it match the index
    count[total-2] = count[total-2] +1
for x in range(11):
    print("You rolled " + str(count[x]) + " " + str(x+2)+ "'s")
```

Comment: This is close to what I had before, can you explain the count[total-2] = count[total-2] + 1 ?  Thanks!

Comment: This is due to the code itself since index counting starts with 0. In correspondence of index-count, we have: 0-2,1-3,2-4...10-12

Comment: Awesome I think I'm getting it.  The last part I\m a bit confused on is when you call x in print.  How does it know what the count of the total is?

Comment: Got it, did not spot the X when you first set the count list.  Makes perfect sense now and is very close to what I was attempting to do the first time.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary in this case.
Or specifically [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

roll_scores = defaultdict(int)
rolls = 10

for _ in range(rolls):
    die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    total = die1 + die2

    print("Roll 1: ", die1)
    print("Roll 2:", die2)
    print("Total:", total)

    roll_scores[total] +=1

for k in roll_scores:
    print("You rolled {} {}'s".format(roll_scores[k], k))
```

But if you want to use a list, the concept is almost identical.
changing roll_scores to a 13 item list (0 to 12):

```
roll_scores = [0]*13
```

And change the print at the end:

```
for i in range(len(roll_scores)):
    print("You rolled {} {}'s".format(roll_scores[i], i))
```